# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when using DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime

I have below piece of code to log the message. Since I wanted to have the log for each `date` I tried to retrieve current `date` and then tried to create log file with that particular date with format `path/dd_mm_yyyy_LogFile.txt`. Before that I had to retrieve current `date` without time.

```
StreamWrite sw=null;
var d = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd_MM_yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//Error in the above line  
sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + d + "_LogFile.txt", true);
sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + message);
```

But am getting **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**. I followed many other posts like changing the `"dd_MM_yyyy"` to `"dd-MM-yyy"` or to `"d-m-yyyy"` but unfortunately am still hitting the same error. What else am missing here? Below screenshot for reference. If you see the screenshot, I've proper `d` value fetched. But still the above exception.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried 'dd-MM-yyyy'?

Comment: If the string is `"2/26/2016"` then shouldn't the format string be `"MM/dd/yyyy"`?

Comment: you said "changing the "dd_MM_yyyy" to "dd-MM-yyy" or to "d-m-yyyy"" - but the date at the screenshot is in "dd/MM/yyy" format

Comment: You should utilize the `using` statement. Something like `using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, d + "_LogFile.txt"), true)) { /* ... */ }` is better. It ensures the file stream is properly disposed in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `d` like this instead:

```
var d = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy");
```

`ToShortDateString()` does not have the format you want.

Comment: Well this is one of the good approach.. and easy one too.. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

As I can see from the picture, you actually want `"M/d/yyyy"` format:

```
  String d = @"2/26/2016"; // d's value has been taken from the screenshot
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format string in Parse method should exactly match the one produced by `ToShortDateString`. e.g. this works with me:

```
var d = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
Console.WriteLine(d);

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(d, @"MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

output:

```
02/26/2016                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
02/26/2016 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the screen shot you posted.  The runtime value of the string is:

```
"2/26/2016"
```

So the format string should be:

```
"M/dd/yyyy"
```

or:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy"
```

By using those other format strings, you're explicitly telling the system to use that *exact* format.  And the string you have doesn't match that format.  Hence the error.